# MathML in Firefox OS

Tags: firefox-os, mathml

I am doing a small project where I write mathematical texts in HTML using MathML. When I test it on Firefox, the results are as expected, everything is displayed as expected.

However, in Firefox OS 2.0 (that I would expect to work in the same way), there are problems with characters like the real set (ℝ) or the star (⋆), which are displayed as gray blocks.

Is this a problem with Firefox OS or there are specific tags to be notified on the HTML that allow these symbols to be correctly interpreted? Or is there another way to represent this symbols?

Comment: What device and build are you using? You also may want to have a look at this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=775060

Comment: I'm using the build 200141008000202 of 2.0.0 on a ZTE Open C. I will take a look at the bug, as soon as I understand it.

Comment: Ok, it seems that my build is from some days before the font update. I will try to rebuild it and see if it works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are seen is the [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29#Replacement_character), often a black diamond with a white question mark, �, that in Firefox OS is a gray block.

Why you seen the replacement character only in Firefox OS? Because only Firefox OS hasn't the character that you need. As [Jason Weathersby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1655387/jason-weathersby) already mention, you should check https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=775060.

Last year I worked with Firefox OS and MathML for Google Summer of Code, https://r-gaia-cs.github.io/gsoc2014/, and had to build my own image of Firefox OS to have properly fonts available. If you want to try build your own image of Firefox OS with fonts that support MathML, read http://ftb.rgaiacs.com/2015/03/16/math_at_firefox_os.html.

Gays blocks normally means that the font that you are using doesn't has the character.

Comment: I managed to install some more recent builds and the result is the same, so I will have to build it myself, I will follow your guide. For some reason gaia and gecko are not being fetched now, probably some temporary problem, I will wait a little more. Thank you! Do you know if someday these fonts will come with the standard build?

Comment: > Do you know if someday these fonts will come with the standard build?

This only depends on Mozilla and its partners (since they can remove the fonts when flashing the device). Please send a email to dev list saying that you want that they include this fonts.